# How to use the PRNG linear congruential generator for rolling one dice in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I have to design a linear congruential generator for rolling one dice in Matlab. The general equation I use is defined by the recurrence relation:

[image]

where a,b en c are large and positive values.
The result of the generator is obtained by dividing vector R by the largest number possible in R, (c-1).

I got two set of constants [a,b,c] and somehow, for the constants reported below in my code, it is possible to throw 0 with the dice. This does not happen all the times, but lets say 50% times when I run the code. Furthermore, I throw rarely 7's, which I try to prevent by the line  'Prevent throwns of 7'.
Strangely, I do not have these problems when I use  a = 1664525, b = 1013904223 and c = 2^32.

How is this possible and how can I solve this? Or does it have something to do with the constants?

```
function [out_2] = ThrowDie_2(N,F,a,b,c)
N = 5000; % amount of times the die is thrown
F = 6; % amount of faces of die
a = 3223; 
b = 3323;
c = 3486;
seed = now %Time of the system, the whole part of t corresponds to the date, 
        % and the fractional part corresponds to the time of day. Use
        % format longG to see the decimals. The time of the system will be
        % used as the initial seed for the LCG. 
out_int_2(1) = seed; %The initial value, seed that determines the sequence
    for i=2:N+1
        out_int_2(i) = mod(a.*out_int_2(i-1).*seed+b,c);
        out_2(i) = (out_int_2(i)/(c-1))*F;
        seed = out_2(i);  
    end
if out_2(2:N+1)<=6 ;  %Prevent throwns of 7
  out_2 = ceil(out_2(2:N+1));
else out_2 = round(out_2(2:N+1));
end 
end
```

Comment: What language is the code ? Please edit and add relevant tag.

Comment: It is in Matlab, sorry for not mentioning this.

Comment: You should probably round down (`floor`) and add 1 to avoid 0s in your output. `round` will cause an uneven distribution of output values. Also, the choice of constants change the probabilities of the various output values, picking the right constants is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hull-Dobell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Period_length) gives necessary and sufficient conditions for a LCG `x -> (a*x+b) mod c` to be maximal-period. One of them is that all of the prime factors of `c` divide `a-1`. Your choice of `a,b,c` fails this. 7 is a prime factor of 3486 which doesn't divide 3222. As a consequence, you have non-zero seeds which lead to zero. For example, A seed of 3310 leads to 0 in just 4 steps.

On the other hand, I don't see how 7 pops up. I can replicate getting `0` but not values `>= c`. Perhaps something about Matlab rounding.